# Multiple Build Output Windows Installer XML

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

I can't figure out, if there is a way to build a wixout and a msi in the same build process.
I gave my visual Studio linker (light.exe) additional parameters:
`-xo -out bin\Release\SdwClientSetup.wixout -bf`

By using

> -xo

no msi File will be created.
Is there a way to create both ***(msi and wixout)*** in one build process?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [toolset diagram](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/tools.html) shows that light takes a .wixout as an input.

If you first produce the .wixout, you can add a step to call light to link it into an .msi.